# EF 6 optional FK , delete still produces error

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, sql-delete

So i have these two simple models

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    private string _Name;
    [Column("sNameColumn")]
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } }

    public  virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int? blog_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("blog_id")]
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't done anything unusual at the dbContext definition. Then , i try to do something like this.

```
 db.Blogs.Remove(db.Blogs.Find(2)); 
 db.SaveChanges();
```

And i get a FK violation error.Notice that the FK blog_id is null-able, so i thought that EF whould handle the delete, and make the corresponding FK Null.
Can you tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Just because the FK column is nullable doesn't mean EF will nullify it when you remove the blog entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entities have to be loaded for EF to be able to handle setting their foreign key to null.

```
var b = db.Blogs.Find(2);
db.Entry(b).Collection(b => b.Posts).Load();
db.Blogs.Remove(b); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any workaround to achieve this behavior without explicitly loading the collection ?

Comment: Also , let's say that Post has another optional fk reference (ex. Comment). Do i have to lazily load the "Comments" collection too (like a chain)?

Comment: If the `Post` has other references, they don't need to be loaded if they aren't affected by deleting `Blog`. If there are multiple relationships with an optional reference to `Blog`, then you would have to load all of them; and with multiple relationships, using multiple `Include`s and `Single` is better than `Find` with `Load`.

Comment: So in other words, you say that if i have multiple relationships , eager loading is the most appropriate method? Can you justify that?

Comment: (You're asking about eager loading as opposed to explicit loading right?) Generally it would be better, because each call to `Load` performs a database query, but multiples calls of `Include` will be combined into a single query. On the other hand, you can't use `Include` with `Find`, since `Find` looks within the context and may not send a request to the database at all. There may be other considerations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Entity Framework can only update entities it has loaded.

Of course there are ways to update database records by raw SQL statements that you can also execute through EF, but that's not the core of EF as ORM.

So if you want to use EF only, you have no choice. You have to load collections in `Blogs` explicitly for them to get dissociated from their parent. For instance by `Include`:

```
var b = db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts).Include(b => b.Comments)
          .Single(b => b.BlogId == 2);
db.Blogs.Remove(b); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or by `Load` as in the other answer.

Another option could be to use [Entity Framework Extented](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). One of its features is batch updates, which allows one-shot update statements of records in an `IQueryable` given a template record. This would look like this:

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;
...
db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogId == 2)
        .Update(p => new Post { BlogId = default(int?) });
db.Blogs.Remove(b); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Only the properties that are set in the template record are modified. To make this transactional, you should wrap all statements in a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: Totally forgot about eager loading, thank god SO exists